How to derive Smarr formula for Kerr Black Hole?
Following is the Smarr formula for Kerr Black Hole
$$M=\frac{\kappa A}{4\pi}+2 \Omega J $$
where $\kappa, \Omega$, $J$ and $A$ are surface gravity, angular velocity, angular momentum and surface area of Kerr Black Hole respectively.
Is there any simple way to derive Smarr formula for Kerr black Holes by using Komar mass and komar angular momentum? How to start this derivation?
Edit
I am reading the following text arXiv:1809.01403v2  [gr-qc]  26 Nov 2018 Black Hole Information and Thermodynamics by Dieter Lüst Ward Vleeshouwers. On page 36-37 he started as follows:
Komar integral associated with a timelike killing vector $\mathcal{E}$ is
$$M_{\mathcal{E}}(V)=-\frac{1}{4\pi} \int dS \sqrt{\gamma} n_{\mu} \sigma_{\nu} \nabla^{\nu} \mathcal{E^\nu}$$
Assume $K=\mathcal{E}-\Omega \phi$ for killing horizon of Kerr black hole, we get
$$M_{k}(S^2_{\infty})=-\frac{1}{4 \pi} \int_{S^2_{\infty}} \nabla^\mu \mathcal{E}^\nu dS_{\mu \nu}$$
$$=-\frac{1}{4 \pi} \int_{\Sigma} R^{\mu}_{\nu} K^{\nu}dS_{\mu}+\frac{1}{4\pi} \int_{\partial B} \nabla^{\mu} K^{\nu} dS_{\mu \nu}$$
I am not getting how to get the last two equations ?

Harvey Reall's notes on Black Holes have a derivation of both the horizon area as well as the surface gravity in the Kerr black hole as far as I can recall. Combining the two you should be able to get the formula you want.

It seems that they used the formula associating killing fields to the ricci tensor and they split the boundary contribution into two parts one at infinity and one at the event horizon of the black hole.
